# Find sublists of an array

Tags: python, list

Given **Arr**=`[10,34,20,19]`, **N**=4, **K**=2, and to obtain the list **Reqd**=`[[[10],[34,20,19]],[[10,34],[20,19]],[[10,34,20],[19]]]`

---

I tried using the `itertools.permutation(Arr,2)`, but did not find the desired result. How do I find the **Reqd** list?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind `Reqd`?

Comment: The Reqd contains all such sublists such that the number of sublists in Reqd[i], where i is in range(len(Reqd)), is equal to K and the elements in the sublists should follow the same order as given in the Arr. If Arr= [1,2,3] and K=2, then the Reqd=[[[1],[2,3]],[[1,2],[3]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
Arr = [10, 34, 20, 19]
N = 4
K = 2


valid_combinations = []


def all_combinations(current):
    s = sum(current)
    if len(current) > K or s > N:
        return

    if s == N and len(current) == K:
        valid_combinations.append(current)
        return

    for val in range(1, N + 1):
        all_combinations(current + [val])


all_combinations([])

out = []
for comb in valid_combinations:
    idx = 0
    out.append([])
    for c in comb:
        out[-1].append(Arr[idx : idx + c])
        idx += c
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[[[10], [34, 20, 19]], [[10, 34], [20, 19]], [[10, 34, 20], [19]]]
```

---

For:

```
Arr = [10, 34, 20, 19]
N = 4
K = 3
```

Prints:

```py
[[[10], [34], [20, 19]], [[10], [34, 20], [19]], [[10, 34], [20], [19]]]
```